# Does anyone know what the gs_lcp tracker is for in a google search query?

Tags: google

Someone had shared a search query they had with friends only to discover the URL had a query parameter called gs_lcp with a long identifier which seems to be base64 encoded.

Decoding it to ascii yielded a string that starts with `￹psy-ab` and ends with `gws-wiz�￹` and has a middle part divides into chunks by `:`

They wonder what information that tracking string revealed about them.

The only relevant results I found about psy-ab were a couple threads of people claiming the tracking ID spread from computer to computer by who ever used it. They were scared it was malicious, though of course it was most likely the work of a company who once said don't be evil.

Ex:
https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/429037/google-search-url-highly-suspicious/
https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/77b4j8/what_is_psyab_in_google_links/du2gkey/

If anyone knows the purpose of that parameter.